# getting data from a class object

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void btnset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Student newstudent = new Student();
    {
        newstudent.Forename = txtforename.Text;
        newstudent.Surname = txtsurname.Text;
        newstudent.Course = txtcourse.Text;
        newstudent.DoB = txtdob.Text;
        newstudent.Matriculation =int.Parse(txtmatric.Text);
        newstudent.YearM = int.Parse(txtyearm.Text);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get data from an object, the program I am creating right now, currently involves 3 buttons:

1. `set` (which sets data in text boxes and creates a new `Student`)
2. `clear` (which clears mentioned text boxes)
3. `get`.

I am having trouble with `get`, as it involves recovering the data after it was cleared, which requires getting data from `newstudent` and I am not too sure on how to do that.

Edit: I should also add that student is a separate class that I am creating this data from

Comment: The combo `Student.Forename` and `newstudent.Surname` looks weird. That can't be right.

Comment: It kind of looks like you're looking for `Binding`.  The beauty of `WPF` is definately the ability to bind to data and for the GUI to update via that.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx

Comment: no you are right, that is me trying various ways to get the data.

Comment: You need to think about your variable scope newstudent only exist in your bntset_click method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guesss you want to reuse the student once it was created from other places. Then use a property  instead of a local variable:

```
private  Student NewStudent { get; set; }

private void btnset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewStudent = new Student();
    NewStudent.Forename = txtforename.Text;
    NewStudent.Surname = txtsurname.Text;
    NewStudent.Course = txtcourse.Text;
    NewStudent.DoB = txtdob.Text;
    NewStudent.Matriculation = int.Parse(txtmatric.Text);
    NewStudent.YearM = int.Parse(txtyearm.Text);
}
```

Now you can access the object from the other event handlers as well.

Comment: @JoshuaAiroConlinTaylor: Then give it a default value by assigning `new Student()`. Or check if it's null when you access it.

Answer (score 0):

your `newStudent` variable only exists within the scope of the btnSet_Click function.  You probably want a class variable to access `newStudent` in your btnGet_Click function.

Really though, I'm not sure what your overarching goal is

Comment: Not necessarily, Add a  `SaveStudent(newStudent)` call at the end and then the scope is quite OK.

Answer (score 0):

In your class declare a variable to hold the `Student` data, like this:

```
Student theStudent;
```

The `new`ing up of the `Student` in the "set" method will take care of creating and storing the data for the `Student` object.

Now in your "get" button's click handler, you can get `theStudent`'s values, like this:

```
private void btnget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtforename.Text = theStudent.Forename;
    txtsurname.Text = theStudent.Surname;
    txtcourse.Text = theStudent.Course;
}
```